# Find a polynomial $f (x)$ whose constant term $f (0)$ has at least $12$ divisors but with this condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find a polynomial $f (x)$ whose constant term $f (0)$ has at least $12$ divisors, but such that $f(a) = 1$ for some $a\neq0$

I could do this the normal way. But apparently I'm supposed to use the fact that if $r$ is a root of $f(x)$, since $(x-r)$ divides $f(x)$, $(a-r)$ divides $f(a)$. I'm confused because since $f(a) = 1$, we must have $(a-r) = 1$ or $(a-r) = -1$.

This would imply that $r = a - 1$ or $r= a+1$.

Then I could try to multiply out $(x-a-r)(x-a+1)$ to get a polynomial. However this does not seem to work for all $a$. Any advice?

Comment: Must this be monic? \

Comment: Is there a reason for reposting [the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513792/find-a-polynomial-f-x-whose-constant-term-f-0-has-at-least-12-divisors-but?lq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the product of
12 distinct primes.

Then
$f(x)
=(m+1)x-m
$
satisfies
$f(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working in $\mathbb Z[x]$, and $a$ is some given non-zero integer.

$f(a)=1 \implies (x-a) \mid (f(x)-1)$, so let $f(x) = g(x)(x-a)+1$.  So $f(0) = 1-a\cdot g(0)$.

Now if $a \neq \pm1$, selecting $g(0) = a^3$ looks a good idea, as you get $f(0) = 1-a^4$, which has divisors $a-1, a+1, a^2+1, a^2-1, a^3+a^2+a+1, a^3-a^2+a-1 $ as divisors, in addition to $1, a^4-1$ and their additive inverses.

If $a=\pm1$, set $g(0) = m\pm1$, where $m$ is any integer with $12$ or more divisors.

The rest of the coefficients and degree of $g(x)$ are left to your choice...